# Windows 10 Linux Subsystem How to Change User Name and PC Name for Bash Console

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

When I first installed and ran Windows Linux Subsystem, console askded me to enter a new user name for bash. I input `User`. Now when I start bash in my console my username and PC name appeared at the beginning of the prompt, like

```
User@DESKTOP-TPQIRNP:/mnt/...
```

What should I do if I want to change my username for bash console? And PC name

Comment: You change the PC Name in Windows, same way you have always done so, how you change the username your logged into should be simply su'ing as that user.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. But how to change user name for bash ? If I will change user name in windows it's don't change in bash console

Comment: If you have changed the PC Name, and your Windows username, and it isn't showing up in bash then you will have to reset the environment.  I already suggest how you switch users within bash though.

Comment: You can switch "hosts" by simply using `ssh hostname`.  Look at the configuration page to determine what your current hosts are.  Two should already exist, the one your currently trying to access and the one you previously created.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to therobyouknow's comment, `LxRun.exe` is deprecated now.

Please refer to [Mitchell Van Manen's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1280390/540660) if you're using the new version of subsystem.

====================================================================

You should use `LxRun.exe` command locating in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.

Here are two solutions, which are all run in `cmd.exe` instead of `bash`.

- Use the command below to create a new user and set it as the default user:

  ```
  LxRun.exe /setdefaultuser NEW_USER
  ```
- **OR** Uninstall Linux subsystem fully and reinstall it

  ```
  LxRun.exe /uninstall /full
  LxRun.exe /install
  ```

  The next time you reenter bash, it will prompt you to input username.

Comment: For a newer version of the subsystem (i.e. one downloaded/upgraded-to as of date of this comment), one would need use the answer provided by @Mitchell Van Manen - https://superuser.com/a/1280390/21353 (I found that answer to work). Otherwise you get: `Warning: lxrun.exe is only used to configure the legacy Windows Subsystem for Linux distribution`

Comment: @therobyouknow thanks for the reminder! I've updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome +1 upvote on your comment oryxfea and answer and also +1 upvote on Mitchell Van Manen's answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

In the new version of the subsystem, the command is (from elevated cmd.exe):

`C:\> ubuntu run sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername`

this way you will circumvent logging in with the old username first.

Comment: This solved it for me with the newer version of subsystem.

Comment: ```C:\> ubuntu run sudo usermod -l newUsername -p /home/newUsername -m oldUsername``` also renames home folder

Comment: @PavK. I believe there's a typo in your answer:  The "-p" (which is for passwords) should be "-d" (which is for changing the home directory).  At least that was what worked on my system.

Comment: The comment with @IvyMike correction worked well for me.
Had to remember to change the `"startingDirectory"` setting in the Windows Terminal settings, or equivalent, if using it to start in your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Article [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816131/how-to-change-the-git-bash-username-on-windows).

You have to create a ssh_config and put your username into it. The location within the Windows Linux Subsystem is `/mnt/%windir%/windows`

Create `~/.ssh/config` file and name write your username inside the file like:

```
user New_User_Name
```

You do not have to worry about permissions.

Comment: Thanks. When I should create `~/.ssh/config` file ? Where in Windows is root Windows Linux Subsystem directory ? How can I find it ?

Comment: it's `/mnt/%windir%/windows`

Comment: I think this is more for Git Bash not the new Windows Linux Subsystem,